# How do I properly link ttf and/or woff files in my CSS and HTML?

Tags: html, css, truetype, woff

I have found many answers here without registering, but this procedure one has me stumped so I need help.

I discovered @font-face and the link href method a couple of weeks ago and simply speaking, I don't understand what to do to make it work.

My mark-up:

HTML

```
<!-- FONT FROM RBBT.NET USED ON THIS BOARD DESIGN //-->
<link href="http://rbbt.net/css?family=aspire-demibold" rel="stylesheet">
```

CSS

```
/* SPECIAL: FONT FROM RBBT.NET USED ON THIS MESSAGE BOARD */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'aspire-demibold';
  src: url('http://rbbt.net/aspire-demibold.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
  url('http://rbbt.net/aspire-demibold.woff') format('woff'); /* Modern Browsers */
}

h1 {
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:center;
  font-family: 'aspire-demibold', cursive;
  letter-spacing: .125em;
  color: #000067;
  font-size: 9em;
  font-weight: 700
}
```

Something is working correctly since the special font does show in my Android phone when I visit the message board here: http://bripples.runboard.com/

But the font does not show when I use my home computer. I do not know what, if anything, I am doing incorrectly. How do I determine what is working correctly in my coding and what is not behaving the way I wish it to be. Could someone here explain this to me and help me understand? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Its the issue of [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) when opening the [URL](http://bripples.runboard.com/) on your home computer. The *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* headers are absent on the given website, hence the fonts are not able to load when called in *@fontface*. You can try manually downloading the font, store it in your local folder and use that address in your code.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'aspire-demibold';
src: url('../fonts/aspire-demibold.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* 
Safari, Android, iOS */
url('../fonts/aspire-demibold.woff') format('woff'); /* Modern 
Browsers */
}
```

Please do remember to add the *ttf* and *woff* as *MIME types* in your web server. This will surely work.

Comment: That worked. I can see the font locally now which helps me immensely when designing the site. I still don't understand how it works or how to tell if I mess something up, but the template style is a big help.

Comment: I personally prefer to keep all font I'm using at my sites in `fonts` folder and use font-face generator to convert font files in web format. I like to use this font-face generator https://everythingfonts.com/font-face but actually there are a lot of them in internet.

Comment: @Pelinor None of this was the problem with the code, in a simple manner the browser was unable to access the font files present on the given urls. For further reference you can check this out -[https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp]

Comment: Thank you all for the "hand-holding." I was worried about messing this up when it should have been easy. I tell others not to worry but have trouble taking my own advice at times.